# how to control twillo sms title?

Tags: java, android, sms, twilio

I got this code:

```
 public void send(String body) throws TwilioRestException {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", phoneNumber));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", phoneNumber));
```

//        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Title", title));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", body));
        Message sms = messageFactory.create(params);
    }

and I got this sms:

[image]

Is there a way to control the `"sent from your trail account"` ?

Is there any meaning to `title` in sms?

Comment: "Is there a way to control the 'sent from your trail account' ?" - Not with a trial account, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Mike M is correct. That message is due to using a [trial account](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-twilios-free-trial-work) to [send sms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages).